# Java Kerberos Authentication

Tags: java, http, kerberos

This might be vague or ambiguous, but I have to ask. I want to authenticate to a Kerberized service through Java. Is there any specific way to perform this if I have the krb5.conf and the server's keytab file?

Or, what method would you recommend to perform this?

Comment: What is a _"kerberized network"_?

Comment: Network protected with Kerberos

Comment: Again, what does that mean? Kerberos allows secure mutual authentication of a specific client and a specific service, across an unsecure network (cf. Wikipedia). It has nothing to do with securing the network itself.

Comment: I must've been clear. I am trying to communicate with a server that is protected by Kerberos. I've figured out a simple method to do this. I'll be posting that as an answer soon.

Comment: As Samson pointed out, the OP was referring to "Kerberized service" but incorrectly wrote it as "kerberized network".  I've changed that phrasing in the question so as to not confuse future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out a way to do this.

So, there's this [SourceForge project](http://spnego.sourceforge.net/) which enables "Integrated Windows Authentication and Authorization in Java". If you have a service account in the server, you can pass that credentials in your Java code and get the server to authenticate you. It's available in Maven - [Spnego Maven Dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sourceforge.spnego/spnego/7.0)

Sample code for reference, taken from [Spnego API Docs](http://spnego.sourceforge.net/api/index.html)

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
         System.setProperty("java.security.krb5.conf", "krb5.conf");
         System.setProperty("sun.security.krb5.debug", "true");
         System.setProperty("java.security.auth.login.config", "login.conf");

         SpnegoHttpURLConnection spnego = null;

         try {
             spnego = new SpnegoHttpURLConnection("spnego-client", "username", "password");
             spnego.connect(new URL("http://medusa:8080/index.jsp"));

             System.out.println(spnego.getResponseCode());

         } finally {
             if (null != spnego) {
                 spnego.disconnect();
             }
         }
     }
```

Thanks to [Arunav Sanyal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2185573/arunav-sanyal) for the help :)